# Exporting Hive table to csv/tsv in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I use the following code to export table from hive to hdfs in csv/tsv format.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/xyz/dem_data/science_data'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
SELECT *
FROM science_data;
```

When I view the copied file in hdfs I see a lot of characters like this

```
??=%??0nother episod?/aAj%?is   ?a???$of J horse!de9?amA?se0(
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong. 
Do I need to have some kind of encoding to this to get clean text. The actual files have clean text.

Comment: can you show the content of the able. `select * from science_data limit 3`

Comment: @GaurangShah https://imgur.com/jTcrk0o Uploaded the image here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with local directory using command given below:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/cloudera/Desktop/xyz/science_data' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE select * from table_name;
```